# convert of the object (image) to another object (Byte) in three layers(3-tier)

Tags: c#, architecture, 3-tier

Conversions can be done in the first layer ( UI ) ?

Comment: Conversion *can* take place anywhere. The question is wheter it *should*, and that entirely depends on what your application is doing, and how. You will need to provide some more information to get any useful answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to image in 3-tier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447438/convert-string-to-image-in-3-tier)

Comment: never to convertion in the UI that is bad practice

Comment: @CoffeeCode :  Why? Where the conversion is done

Comment: @ Fredrik Mörk : Each layer can be converted? Even ِDAL(DataAccessLayer).

Comment: do the convertion on the model level. convetions must be done in the backend not frontend

Answer (score 1):

For these kind of operations I personally create a **Utils** `class/namespace` under project `namespace` (`myProjectNamespace.Utils`). A `ststic` class with `public static` members for conversions, formatting, calculations...

Put this class in `BLL` (Business Logic Layer) most of the time but sometimes you need different `Utils` for different layers.

Comment: BLL is not for validation. It's a good place for putting Logic. Most of the time `Utils` best place is there in compare to `UI` or `DAL`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an image is an input - inputs usually come into a system through:

- The frontend interface / UI.
- A backend interface (service).
- An API call.

If the input is specific to - say the UI - then that would suggest it was a UI specific thing and should sit there.

The same rule / principle applies for the other input 'channels'.

if the API being called is in the BL then that's where it might sit.

Where Yousefvand is coming from (and which I agree with) is that if more than one component is using it then it's probably be a good candidate for putting in some osrt of reusable library.

So...

> > Conversions can be done in the first layer ( UI ) ?

Yes **if** the what you're converting is specific to the UI / UI technology being used; otherwise you **could** but probably shouldn't - in this case you'd probably be better implementing your converter in a utility.